# Weird behaviour in SimpleXMLElement Object when printing the array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, php-5.5

I'm struggling with an array in my `SimpleXMLElement Object`. Somehow I don't get the expected result when I print the array `$node->reference`.

**`print_r($node);` shows:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [reference] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [resourceIdentifier] => 52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [resourceIdentifier] => 52cbccc3-b754-4e88-9238-5d5257f9796a
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

**But `print_r($node->reference);` and `print_r($node->reference->children());` shows:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [resourceIdentifier] => 52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a
        )

)
```

**I expect to see:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [resourceIdentifier] => 52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a
                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [resourceIdentifier] => 52cbccc3-b754-4e88-9238-5d5257f9796a
                )

        )

)
```

**Edit**

Here is some code to reproduce:

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
    <item>
        <reference resourceIdentifier="52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a" />
        <reference resourceIdentifier="52cbccc3-b754-4e88-9238-5d5257f9796a" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <reference resourceIdentifier="52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <reference resourceIdentifier="52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a" />
        <reference resourceIdentifier="52chgb7f-1a00-4eaf-ac8a-5d4557f9796a" />
        <reference resourceIdentifier="52cbccc3-b754-4e88-9238-5d5257f9796a" />
    </item>
</items>';

$items = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($items as $item) {

    echo '<h1>Item</h1>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($item);
    print_r($item->reference); // Returns always 1 SimpleXMLElement Object?
    print_r($item->reference->children()); // Returns always 1 SimpleXMLElement Object?
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Comment: Try `print_r($node->reference->children());`

Comment: @user3584460 unfortunately I get the same result as `print_r($node->reference);`

Comment: I added some code to reproduce.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote the question 0.0

Comment: OK, I think that this is the expected and desired behavior. [Example #4 from SimpleXML's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) states the following: `Properties ($movies->movie in previous example) are not arrays. They are iterable and accessible objects.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is: don't rely on `print_r`. The thing with SimpleXML is that it uses a lot of, for want of a better word, "magic", and `print_r` (and `var_dump`, `var_export`, and pretty much any other generic debug or serialize function) doesn't show you how it will behave. Also, and this is really important, **a SimpleXMLElement does not contain any arrays**.

I wrote [a dedicated debug function](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) which, while not perfect, does a better job of recursing through SimpleXML objects than the native ones.

The reason for this specific behaviour is that you can use `$node->reference` to refer to *either* the list of all children called `reference`, *or* the first such child. The following are all equivalent:

```
// Access as iterable list
foreach ( $node->reference as $ref ) {
    echo $ref['resourceIdentifier'];
    // only loop once
    break;
}

// Access as numerically indexed array
echo $node->reference[0]['resourceIdentifier'];

// Access first item by default
echo $node->reference['resourceIdentifier'];
```

This is extremely handy when you have a document that is "deep but narrow", e.g.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<foo><bar><baz><quux hello="world" /></baz></bar></foo>');
echo $xml->bar->baz->quux['hello']; // world
```

Rather than you having to check whether a node is unique or multiple, SimpleXML just lets you write such an expression and ignore any multiples:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<foo><bar><baz><quux hello="world" /><quux ignored="true" /></baz></bar><bar>ignored</bar></foo>');
echo $xml->bar->baz->quux['hello']; // world
```